# revert a git change to a particular file

Tags: git

I am a beginner to git,I made changes to 4 files, added and committed changes.Then pulled from master for new updates and pushed all to master.On opening a pull request, I see a file that shows code changes that I haven't made.How do I revert changes to that particular file in a commit?

Comment: in minimum number of steps so that I don't mess things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git checkout <commit hash> <file path> # Give me an older state of this file
git commit -a                          # Commit older file
```

or:

```
git revert --no-commit <commit hash> # Revert commit, but let me make changes
git reset                            # Unstage everything
git add <file path>                  # Stage only desired file
git checkout -- .                    # Discard all unstaged changes
git commit
```

Comment: git checkout <commit hash> <file path> the commit hash here has to be one before the offending commit correct?

Comment: Correct.  It is the hash of the commit that contains the desired version of the file (which should be the one immediately before the bad commit).